# Invalidate Later in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am using

```
invalidateLater(5000, session)
```

in my Shiny code and it is working. Every 5 seconds I have a query that is refreshed and  a plot is updated. BUT the screen and plots go GRAY every 5 seconds so it looks like the page is dead while the updating occurs. Is there a way to make ONLY the plots update and have the page avoid looking like it's dead?

@JOhn - THank you here is my ui.r

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("tst"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("n", "Number of plots", value=2, min=1, max=7),
    width = 2
  ),
  mainPanel(
    # This is the dynamic UI for the plots
    uiOutput("plots")

  )
))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that when something is being updated, the default .css gives it a class of `.recalculating` and that is what makes it look gray. You can fix this by putting

```
tags$style(type="text/css",
  ".recalculating { opacity: 1.0; }"
)
```

in your `ui.r` or putting the equivalent in you `.css` ifyou are using one. Obviously, if you know CSS you can experiment with other ideas as well.

Comment: John- Thank you. I searched the mainpanel but I don't see where to put the tags.  I have added my ui.r Can you advise where to put the tags? Thank you!

Comment: @user3022875 You can put it right after `pageWithSidebar(`. You might want to wrap it in`tags$head()` but I am not sure it is required. Check here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html for details on `.css` with shiny.