# Strange behavior of R Shiny reactiveValues() and invalidateLater()

Tags: r, shiny

I have a use case where am visualizing operational data for a dashboard. I would like it to be such that the visualization is updated periodically as data is added to the database. The logic in my mind is to first check if the number of rows in the live database table is equal to the number of rows in the corresponding dataframe within R. If yes, then no need to pull data, if no, then pull data from database. What I want to avoid is to just pull data (actual database table has over 5 million rows) periodically regardless of whether there is new data or not.

I have created a subset of the data [here](https://github.com/kilimba/data/blob/master/reactiveTestData.csv). The code below I wrote as a proof of concept to first wrap my head around how `invalidateLater()` and `reactiveValues()` work in R and how I could possibly use them. It simply reads the number of rows in the database table and displays it to the user. If the number of rows changes, the user interface is updated with the new number of rows. Note that to reproduce you may want to put data into a database so you can simulate adding and deleting rows to see reaction of the "app". I used postgres, and an ODBC connection. If you run the code as-is, you will notice that when rows are added to the db, when the app is doing the checking, the user interface (`textOutput()` widget) grays out for a few seconds and appears to be in a state of meditation before eventually correctly displaying the new number of rows. This is using the code which first checks if there are differences in row numbers between database and value held in R.

However if I comment out that part of the code which check for differences (comment out the block below)

```
sharedValues$data <- if(!is.null(sharedValues$data)){
      if(nrow(sqlFetch(conn2,"test2")) == sharedValues$data){
        return(sharedValues$data)
      }
    }
    else{
      sharedValues$data <- nrow(sqlFetch(conn2,"test2"))
      return(sharedValues$data)
    }
```

and instead just pull data periodically regardless if there is a change or not (uncomment this line)

```
#sharedValues$data <- nrow(sqlFetch(conn2,"test2"))
```

the interface reacts superbly, there is no lag (graying out of the widget  text) and the new row value is displayed on the user interface.

My question is what causes the "lag-like" behavior when running the first alternative (which is the desired alternative) of first checking for database changes before making an expensive database select query), yet when the code is amended to pull data regardless of database changes (which seems to me inefficient) this lag-like behavior rears its ugly head? The entire code is below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rCharts)
library(curl)
library(RODBC)

conn2 <- odbcConnect("postgres") # database connection object

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(textOutput("text1"),width = 6)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {  

  sharedValues <<- reactiveValues()
  observe({
    invalidateLater(30000,session)   
    cat("updating data...\n")
    sharedValues$data <- if(!is.null(sharedValues$data)){
      if(nrow(sqlFetch(conn2,"test2")) == sharedValues$data){
        return(sharedValues$data)
      }
    }
    else{
      sharedValues$data <- nrow(sqlFetch(conn2,"test2"))
      return(sharedValues$data)
    }

     #sharedValues$data <- nrow(sqlFetch(conn2,"test2"))
  })

  output$text1 <- renderText({

    y <- sharedValues$data
    return(y)

  })  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094844/invalidate-later-in-shiny) answer, this can be fixed by manipulating the CSS in ui.R

```
tags$style(type="text/css",
  ".recalculating { opacity: 1.0; }"
)
```